# How do I get the fill color of an svg element without rendering it?

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to access a svg element online which I have the URL for but without showing it on the screen.  The svg has only one fill color.  Is there a way with javascript to grab this color? ("#013299")

```
<svg width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 50 50" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g id="mysvg" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <rect id="Background" fill="#013299" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50"></rect>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fetch` to download the SVG and parse it as text, then set the innerHTML of a new DIV to that text, and then it'll be just like any other SVG in a div, except you don't need to append it to the DOM anywhere:

```
const container = document.createElement('div');
fetch(SVG_URL)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {
      container.innerHTML = text;
      const fillColor = container.getElementById('Background').getAttribute('fill');
    })
    .catch(console.error);
```

The `console.error` can be changed to your own error handling callback if the SVG can't be downloaded for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the background fill using basic DOM manipulation:

```
let backgroundFill = document.getElementById("Background").getAttribute("fill")
```